# YahooQF returns incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I'm trying to get markt capitalization from brazil stocks, but I'm getting an error in mycode

This is my code

```
what_metrics <- yahooQF(c("Market Capitalization"))
getQuote("PINE3.SA", what=what_metrics)
```

This is the error I get

```
> Error in sq[, "exchangeTimezoneName"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error likely comes from the fact that the yahoo data in quantmod does not look at stocks traded in Brazil - try e.g. "SPY" instead of "PINE3.SA" and see if that also gives you the error. You could perhaps download the Bovespa data and analyze it with quantmod - see: https://github.com/palencar/BovespaID.